# I am trying to understand how websockets work & to the extent that they are dependent on proxy servers

Tags: websocket

I came across this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262543/what-are-good-resources-for-learning-html-5-websockets) & then to [this article](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Web-Sockets-Proxy-Servers) through that question.

From what I understand, both encrypted / non-encrypted websocket connections are dependent on the proxy servers sending across the proper header/s.

From the article on unencrypted websocket connections

> In case the unencrypted WebSocket traffic flows through a transparent proxy on its way to the WebSocket server, the connection is likely to fail in practice, since the browser does not >issue the CONNECT method in this case. When a proxy server forwards a request to the >(WebSocket) server, it is expected to strip off certain headers, including the Connection >header. Therefore, a well-behaved transparent proxy server will cause the WebSocket >upgrade >handshake to fail almost immediately.
>   Not all proxy servers conform to the HTTP standard regarding expected proxy behavior. For example, some proxy servers are configured not to remove the Connection: Upgrade header and pass it on to the WebSocket server, which in turn sends the 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake response. Problems then arise when the client or the server starts sending the first WebSocket frame. Since the frame does not resemble anything the proxy server might expect (such as regular HTTP traffic), some exception will likely occur, unless the proxy server is specifically configured to handle WebSocket traffic.

On encrypted web socket connections

> In the case of transparent proxy servers, the browser is unaware of the proxy server, so no HTTP CONNECT method is sent. However, since the wire traffic is encrypted, intermediate transparent proxy servers may simply allow the encrypted traffic through, so there is a much better chance that the WebSocket connection will succeed if Web Sockets Secure is used.

If unencrypted connections are expected to fail & encrypted connections only have a better chance of success, how does it even work?!!

I have most likely got this whole thing wrong, but am curious to understand how this works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an encrypted connection, proxies doesn't see the HTTP-content so they simply pass the messages through. But in a non-encrypted connection HTTP-messages (e.g. headers) may be inspected and changed (in some cases) by the Proxies, so in some cases they need to have support for WebSockets as WebSocket-messages doesn't look like HTTP-messages (e.g. no HTTP-headers).

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that the article you refer to was written by someone who works for a company that produces a product that is designed to solve these problems. As such, there may be an incentive for the author to exaggerate the extent of the problems.

For example, the author says that:

> [a transparent proxy] is expected to strip off certain headers, including the Connection header

This is not true. According to RFC2616:

> A "transparent proxy" is a proxy that does not modify the request or
>   response beyond what is required for proxy authentication and
>   identification

Of course, many proxies do not follow the RFCs to the letter, so it is still a good idea to use an encrypted connection.

TLS encryption is specifically designed to prevent intermediate servers interfering with your traffic. If an intermediate proxy server is causing problems with a secure WebSockets connection, then you probably have bigger problems, as it could also interfere with other secure traffic, such as the connection between you and your internet banking.